Overrides in package.json doesn't work I got an error
I have a package.json:
    "dependencies": {
      ...,
      "tomato": "^1.0.9",
      "zone.js": "^0.13.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      ...,
      "orange": "^2.7.2"
    }
   }

The tomato package use zone.js ^0.11.4  and orange ^2.2.0 as peerDependencies.
I need to upgrade Angular version and it need to zone.js to be updated to 0.13.0. So I wanted to add overrides for tomato package. I added overrides section to package.json but I don`t understand why it does not work.
"dependencies": {
      ...,
      "tomato": "^1.0.9",
      "zone.js": "^0.13.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      ...,
      "orange": "^2.7.2"
    },
    "overrides": {
      ...,
      "tomato": {
      "zone.js": "0.11.4",
        "orange@2.2.0": {
        "zone.js": "0.11.4"
         }
      }
    }

I got the error when I run npm install:
While resolving: coffee-map-presentation@.0.1
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.13.3
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"^0.13.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer overridden zone.js@"0.11.4" (was ">=0.13.0") from @orange@2.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@orange
npm ERR!   dev @orange@"^2.7.2" from the root project


Am I understanding correctly that you want one package (zone) to use one version of a library (tomato), but you're trying to override that to use a different version of the same library (zone) in a different package (orange)?

I want to tomato package use old version of zone.js
